# Styling browser dialog boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

(from [failblog](http://failblog.org/2010/10/08/epic-fail-photos-cancel-fail/))

Not only the background's been changed but also the buttons. How can this be done?

Comment: There's a reason this is on the FAILblog. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @meder It would be great to customize dialog box layouts. I wouldn't style it like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a screen shot of someone's dialog box.

That person obviously has set a custom theme on their OS with that style. This has not been controlled by the browser or anything that could have been done via the browser.

Comment: So that's totally out of the browser's control?

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the jqueryui dialog box here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

The individual with the browser is probably running a different scheme via the OS which is modifying the dialog box.